# How can I get the feature names from sklearn TruncatedSVD object?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I have the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
df = df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 25), index=dates, columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWXYZ'))

def reduce(dim):
    svd = sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD(n_components=dim, n_iter=7, random_state=42)
    return svd.fit(df)

fitted = reduce(5)
```

how do i get the column names from `fitted`?

Comment: SVD and PCA do not select columns from existing ones. They transform the data to new dimensions using all the available columns. So there is no sense in getting the columns from fitted.

Comment: After some research I realized how misguided I was, I have asked another question on stats.exchange [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/286335/reduce-dimensions-of-a-highly-dimension-data) If you have the time please consider answering it. @VivekKumar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fitted` column names would be SVD dimensions.

Each dimension is a linear combination of input features. To understand what a particular dimension mean take a look at `svd.components_` array - it contains a matrix of coefficients input features are multiplied by.

Your original example, slightly changed:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD

feature_names = list('ABCDEF')
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randn(1000, len(feature_names)), 
    columns=feature_names
)

def reduce(dim):
    svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=dim, n_iter=7, random_state=42)
    return svd.fit(df)

svd = reduce(3)
```

Then you can do something like that to get a more readable SVD dimension name - let's compute it for 0th dimension:

```
" ".join([
    "%+0.3f*%s" % (coef, feat) 
    for coef, feat in zip(svd.components_[0], feature_names)
])
```

It shows `+0.170*A -0.564*B -0.118*C +0.367*D +0.528*E +0.475*F` - this is a "feature name" you can use for a 0th SVD dimension in this case (of course, coefficients depend on data, so feature name also depends on data).

If you have many input dimensions you may trade some "precision" with inspectability, e.g. sort coefficients and use only a few top of them. A more elaborate example can be found in https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/eli5/pull/208 (disclaimer: I'm one of eli5 maintainers; pull request is not by me).

Comment: What I understand is that the new names are telling me how the new dimension got constructed from the old ones, am I correct?

Comment: then thank that was helpful, I have also asked more detailed question on stats.exchange [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/286335/reduce-dimensions-of-a-highly-dimension-data) if you have the time please consider answering it, thanks again.

Answer (score 7):

> In continuation of  Mikhail post.

Assume that you already have `feature_names` from `vectorizer.get_feature_names()` and after that you have called `svd.fit(X)`

Now you can also extract sorted best feature names using the following code:

```
best_fearures = [feature_names[i] for i in svd.components_[0].argsort()[::-1]]
```

The above code, try to return the arguement of descending sort of `svd.components_[0]` and find the relative index from `feature_names` (all of the features) and construct the `best_features` array.
Then you can see for example the 10 best features:

```
In[21]: best_features[:10]

Out[21]: 
['manag',
 'develop',
 'busi',
 'solut',
 'initi',
 'enterprise',
 'project',
 'program',
 'process',
 'plan']
```